# Visual studio 2015 debugging sharepoint 2013 webpart extreme slow and will hang always

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a webpart for sharepoint 2013 using visual studio in C# language.

I'm developing the webpart on the sharepoint server cause I don't have office development kit on my local computer.

I can deploy my webpart to the sharepoint website, however, the whole website's response will be extremely slow (~several minutes till breakpoint being hit). Also, when I try to view the property when it hits the breakpoint, visual studio always hangs and the operation will time out and won't be able to debug.

I've tried viewing on different browsers such as Google chrome, IE.

So is this a normal situation? If not, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you debugging your webpart? Do you select Debug option from the solution explorer or do you attach to the w3wp process?

If you are attaching to the w3wp process, I've seen a lot of developers attaching to all available w3wp processes. It would be more optimal to attach to the specific process for your application.

Can you check your system resource usage when debugging? Chrome windows use a lot of memory and may also be slowing your application down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here's a bit more detail. I just debug by pressing f5. I checked the system resources, there are 10gb ram left will around 10% CPU usage

Answer (score 2):

You have to use attach to the the process from the Debug Menu.